# Invalid keystore format android error after the Keystore got corrupted

Tags: android, keystore

I have uploaded an app back in January to Android Martket and I had to reformat my computer, so I backed up all the files including the Keystore and the key. The bad news is the Keystore was corrupted and cannot work for me in order to release an update.The message that I get is: `invalid keystore format android`. I still have the same pc that created the original Keystore.

Is there a way to replicate the first Keystore?

Comment: did you use character @ # or & in your keystore alias password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there is no way to regenerate the same keystore .So, you cant update the current version of the . 
What you can do is just create a new keystore and launch a complete new version for the app in the market.

Answer (score 1):

All you can do is to try some file restore utilities like GetDataBack in order to try to restore the keystore. No other way exists: without valid keystore you can only generate new one and release an another application.